# new to Ruby, if else statement not working

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Well when Input a number, it doesn't print out any of the strings for the given value. if i put in 100, shouldn't it print "go to server room"?

```
stress = gets.chomp!
def stress
  if stress === 100
    p "Go to server room"
  elsif stress > 50
    puts "Take a break"
  else
    p "Continue working"
  end
end

p stress
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well when Input a number, it doesn't print out any of the strings for the given value. if i put in 100, shouldn't it print "go to server room"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i put in 100, shouldn't it print "go to server room"?

I assume that you want your program to read user input and then print different messages depending on that input.

> [I'm] new to Ruby

Okay, so first of all, Ruby doesn't do implicit type conversion like JavaScript or PHP. Or not to the same extent. It does allow you to compare floats and integers:

```
1.0 == 1 #=> true
```

but comparing strings and integers doesn't work that way:

```
'1' == 1 #=> false
```

You have to convert it yourself:

```
'1'.to_i == 1 #=> true
```

Since your input is supposed to be an integer, we can convert it right away:

```
stress = gets.to_i
```

When entering <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, `gets` will return `"100\n"` and [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) will interpret that as an integer, returning `100` (`to_i` ignores the trailing newline, so we don't need `chomp`).

`stress` is now an integer, so you can compare it to other integers:

```
if stress == 100
  puts "Go to server room"
elsif stress > 50
  puts "Take a break"
else
  puts "Continue working"
end
```

I've changed `===` to `==`. For comparisons you almost always want the latter. `===` has special meaning in Ruby. Just avoid it for now.

The above code would already work, but you wanted a method. You *could* call your method `stress`, i.e. use the same name for the variable and the method. But it makes your code *much* harder to understand. So let's choose a different method name, e.g. `message`. While we're at it, let's also remove the repeated `puts` calls, so it just returns the message without printing it:

```
def message(stress)
  if stress == 100
    "Go to server room"
  elsif stress > 50
    "Take a break"
  else
    "Continue working"
  end
end
```

You can call the above method via:

```
input = gets.to_i
puts message(input) # <- 'puts' is now here
```

I've deliberately chosen a different variable name for the input to distinguish it from the method argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable and your method definition have the same name. Try changing:

```
stress = gets.chomp!
```

to

```
var = gets.chomp!
```

Then set up your method to accept the variable:

```
def stress(s)
  if s.to_i == 100
    p "Go to server room"
  elsif s.to_i > 50
    puts "Take a break"
  else
    p "Continue working"
  end
end

p stress(var)
```

You can also do it close to what you were doing, just use a variable other than the name of your method:

```
var = gets.chomp!
def stress
  if self.to_i == 100
    p "Go to server room"
  elsif self.to_i > 50
    puts "Take a break"
  else
    p "Continue working"
  end
end
```

p var.stress

Comment: `if self = 100`?!

Comment: Typo, fixed it.

Comment: Unless you do `var.extend(Module new { def stress ... end })`, `self` there is btw `main` (if run in irb/pry,) and has no connection to `var`. I wonder who has this upvoted.

Comment: Also `var` is a `String` and comparison against integers will always result in `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here. For one, as someone already mentioned, you are not passing an argument to your method. For another, the `gets` method returns a String, not an integer, so if you pass the result in you are comparing a String to an integer.

Rework your method like this:

```
def stress(level_string)
  level = level_string.to_i
  if level == 100
    "Go to server room"
  elsif stress > 50
    "Take a break"
  else
    "Continue working"
  end
end
```

Now you can try:

```
>> level_string = gets.chomp!
>> 100
#> "100"
>> stress(level_string)
#> "Go to server room"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your statement

```
p stress
```

you output the value of the **variable** named stress, not the value returned by the **method** stress.

You can have a method and a variable of the same name, but then you have to invoke the method using parenthesis:

```
p stress()
```

In your particular case, you would then run however into the next problem: Inside your **method** `stress`, you are in a nested scope, which means that the outside **variable** `stress` is not visible. Hence, in the statement

```
if stress === 100
```

you refer to the **method** stress, i.e. you have a recursion.

There are several possible solutions:

- Pass the variable by parameter
- Change the name of the variable
- Change the name of the method

As a rule of thumb, I recommend to

- never give a variable and a method the same name, and
- do not access variables from outer scope inside a method

unless you have very good reasons to do otherwise.